# How does a .map works?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to delete some information using a map to hold all the selected values and then I press delete and everything should get deleted however am doing only 1 when I select all of them, what am I doing wrong?

```
librosData.filter((x) =>
selectedIDs.has(x.id)).map( x => {
 console.log(x.id)
 let tempLibrosData = librosData;
 tempLibrosData = tempLibrosData.filter(e => e.id != x.id)
 console.log(tempLibrosData)
}
```

This is what the consoles do bring back:

as you can see it brings back 3 IDs but when I filter the ids it only deletes 1 out of the 3? I'm confused shouldn't it delete all?

[image]

**more insight**

I have a localStorage

```
const data = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("verpedidos"))
```

this variable holds a bunch of information:

[image]

I only want to modify the variable inside the information, that is called data.

I pass the info to another variable so I can modify it without affecting anything else

which is `let librosData = data[0].data`

after that then comes the selecting process ->

```
librosData.filter((x) => //where x is the row I have select
selectedIDs.has(x.id)).map( x => { // checks if such id is in the map
console.log(x.id)   //shows all ids
let tempLibrosData = librosData; // variable = data
tempLibrosData = tempLibrosData.filter(e => e.id != x.id) // filter items that match the row.id 
console.log(tempLibrosData) //render the new list of items
```

Comment: Here what is the type of librosData ?

Comment: Can you please fix the syntax errors in your code. It doesn't currently parse, and the way to resolve it matters -- i.e., what does the `.has(x.id))` do there?

Comment: @Saiprashanth librosData is an array

Comment: @ChristianFritz I'm using MUI-DataGrid you have an option to select things using a checkbox and it will draw the info based on that. I have it so that it brings the id of the row.

Comment: @Andy I'm having issues is a bit more complex than what I asked, what I asked was indeed part of the problem but not the whole thing. I have asked separately because each question is a different issue. Is a whole thing with firebase + DataGrid + localStorage i'm slowly getting there.

Comment: I misread the question. Sorry. You should just be setting your state to `[]` if you want to delete everything. No need to use `map` or `filter`.

Comment: @Andy what if I just want to delete 2/3 that's the thing

Comment: But your question is "everything should get deleted". You really still need to write a [mcve] so we can help you. [Here's a how to guide for creating working React snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002). And you need to ask the right question (input, code, expected output) otherwise we're just going to guess, and that's not how this site works.

Comment: my question is how does it works, because what I was trying to do which should work is not working if I select two or more it just doesn't do as intended. Would love to edit the question to add a code but apparently I'm not allowed to lol.

Comment: Are you using checkboxes, and you select them, hit delete, and you want the objects in the data representing those items to be deleted, and the component to be updated, but save the ones that weren't checked?

Comment: If you want to know how `map` works, then read [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: @Andy yes andy that's exactly what I want, and is partially working atm still testing with console.logs

Comment: @gre_gor I though I understood them until I hit this predicament.

Comment: The docs clearly say not to use `map`, if you are not gonna return a new array.

Comment: I have use a map without an issue before to delete whole docs from firebase, I don't see why it would be an issue to use this same method to update data instead of deleting. I'm filtering information and then it updates to firebase is technically deleting but in another way.

Comment: please read the edit on my answer.  You never save the value of librosData on each iteration. So everytime you filter, you are filtering the original array again.

Comment: What's even the point of that `map` there? You aren't even returning anything in that callback. Just `librosData= librosData.filter(x =>
!selectedIDs.has(x.id))` should have been enough.

Comment: The map is "maping" the checked options you selected/clicked. they are "rows" is from the DataGrid from MUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The map() function is used to iterate over an array and manipulate or change data items. In React, the map() function is most commonly used for rendering a list of data to the DOM. - https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-use-the-map()-function-to-export-javascript-in-react

You shouldn't be using map for the case you have described.  You can simply use filter instead of nesting it inside map.

To remove libros that are in the selectedIDs array from librosData :

```
const remainingLibros = librosData.filter(libro => !selectedIDs.has(libro.id))
```

if librosData is a react state variable:

```
setLibrosData(prevState => prevState.filter(libro => !selectedIDs.has(libro.id))
```

EDIT:
if you want to know what is going on with your specific code rather than how you should achieve the functionality you want:

The map function iterates over each item in an array and performs the logic you provide on that item.  Over every iteration you are filtering librosData by a new value but you never update the value of librosData, so the filtering you do is never saved before the next filter. That's why the console log always returns an array with 2 values.

Comment: `selectedIDs` is a `Set`. It has no `includes`. It should be `has` as OP is using.

Comment: Oh so it does one by one I see, idk why I though it would do all of them at same time

Comment: I mean when I use my delete function with all the delete code and stuff, it works when I select one and delete 1 by 1 but if I select all of them (is a checkbox) and then I delete it only deletes the first one and if I hit delete again it only deletes the next one.

Comment: Manage to get it to work, thanks for the advice. wouldn't have done it without it

Answer (score 0):

The `map()` method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

Answer (score -2):

[The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Your map is manipulating the data the way you think it is, but then you're not saving the newly returned array anywhere. I'm assuming based on your code and description that you'd like to alter the original array, so you could do something like this:

```
selectedIDs = selectedIDs.has(x.id)).map( x => {
 console.log(x.id)
 let tempLibrosData = librosData;
 tempLibrosData = tempLibrosData.filter(e => e.id != x.id)
 console.log(tempLibrosData)
}
```

That probably won't exactly work based on what `has(x.id)` is being used for, but hopefully you get the gist.

Comment: `selectedIDs` is probably a `Set`. `has` returns a boolean. You code has syntax errors and the `map` callback still doesn't return anything. OP probably just want's to filter objects out of `librosData` which have the id in `selectedIDs`.